# Multiplicity of the critical point of a product of holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

For $f(z)$ holomorphic at the origin, say that $f$ is

- $0$-lacunary if $f(0) = 0$, and
- $k$-lacunary (for $k\geq 1$) if $f(0), f^{(k)}(0)\neq 0$ and $f^{(\ell)}(0) = 0$ for all $\ell\in[1, k)\cap \mathbb{N}$.

(For example, $\cos z$ would be 2-lacunary and $e^z$ would be 1-lacunary.)

Now suppose that $g(z)$ is $m$-lacunary and $h(z)$ is $n$-lacunary (where $m\leq n$), and that $g(z)h(z)$ is $r$-lacunary.  The following propositions have straightforward proofs:

1. $r \geq m$.
2. If $m < n$ then $r = m$.
3. The converse of (2) is false.

What other interesting propositions can we prove about $m$, $n$, and $r$?  For example, is there an upper bound on $r$?  Can we tell what $r$ is without doing power series multiplication?  Etc.

Comment: What about $g(z)=z^3$ and $h(z)=z^4$? $g(z)h(z)=z^7$ is 7 lacunary and $m=3$, $n=4$

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo Oops!  Good catch: I was assuming that $f(0)\neq 0$.  Fixed.

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo What about them? We have m = 3, n = 4, and r = 3 = m.

Comment: There is no upper bound: For $g(z) = e^z$, $h(z) = e^{-z}$ you have $m=n=1$ and $r = \infty$.